# Convert List<boolean> to String

Tags: c#, string, list, boolean

I got a boolean list with 92 booleans, I want the list to be converted to a string, I thought I ll take 8 booleans(bits) and put them in a Byte(8 bits) and then use the ASCII to convert it the byte value to a char then add the chars to a string. However after googeling for more then 2 hours, no luck atm. I tried converting the List to a Byte list but it didn t work either ^^.

```
String strbyte = null;
for (int x = 0; x != tmpboolist.Count; x++) //tmpboolist is the 90+- boolean list
{
   //this loop checks for true then puts a 1 or a 0 in the string(strbyte)
   if (tmpboolist[x])
   {
      strbyte = strbyte + '1'; 
   }
   else
   {
      strbyte = strbyte + '0';
   }
}

//here I try to convert the string to a byte list but no success
//no success because the testbytearray has the SAME size as the 
//tmpboolist(but it should have less since 8 booleans should be 1 Byte)
//however all the 'Bytes' are 48 & 49 (which is 1 and 0 according to
//http://www.asciitable.com/)
Byte[] testbytearray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strbyte);
```

PS If anyone has a better suggestion on how to code & decode a Boolean list to a String?
(Because I want people to share their boolean list with a string rather then a list of 90 1 and 0s.)

EDIT: got it working now! ty all for helping

```
string text = new string(tmpboolist.Select(x => x ? '1' : '0').ToArray());
byte[] bytes = getBitwiseByteArray(text); //http://stackoverflow.com/a/6756231/1184013
String Arraycode = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Arraycode);
//first it makes a string out of the boolean list then it uses the converter to make it an Byte[](array), then we use the base64 encoding to make the byte[] a String.(that can be decoded later)
```

I ll look into the encoding32 later, ty for all the help again :)

Comment: you need to be more specific on what you want your string to look like

Comment: It's not clear what you want to end up with.  A string that is an ascii encoding of bits, which can then be turned back into booleans?

Comment: `Encoding.Default.GetBytes` does not do what you think it does. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989695/how-to-convert-a-string-of-bits-to-byte-array

Comment: If you want to represent the boolean list with a string, I would suggest using hex characters (0-9, a-f), which packs 4 bits into each character, instead of packing 8 bits into a char. If you pack 8 bits into a char, this will use the full range of 8-bit ascii, which includes some unprintable characters. E.g. value 00000111 = 7 = bell character. Better to represent as 0000 0111 => "07".

Comment: Note that 92 is not evenly divisible by 8. You'll have 4 orphaned bits to deal with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should store your boolean values in a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx).

```
var values = new BitArray(92);
values[0] = false;
values[1] = true;
values[2] = true;
...
```

---

Then you can convert the BitArray to a byte array

```
var bytes = new byte[(values.Length + 7) / 8];
values.CopyTo(bytes);
```

and the byte array to a Base64 string

```
var result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Reversely, you can convert a Base64 string to a byte array

```
var bytes2 = Convert.FromBase64String(result);
```

and the byte array to a BitArray

```
var values2 = new BitArray(bytes2);
```

---

The Base64 string looks like this: `"Liwd7bRv6TMY2cNE"`. This is probably a bit  unhandy for sharing between people; have a look at [human-oriented base-32 encoding](http://philzimmermann.com/docs/human-oriented-base-32-encoding.txt):

> Anticipated uses of these [base-32 strings] include cut-
>   and-paste, text editing (e.g. in HTML files), manual transcription via a 
>   keyboard, manual transcription via pen-and-paper, vocal transcription over 
>   phone or radio, etc.
>
> The desiderata for such an encoding are:
>
> - minimizing transcription errors -- e.g. the well-known problem of confusing 
>     '0' with 'O'
> - embedding into other structures -- e.g. search engines, structured or 
>     marked-up text, file systems, command shells
> - brevity -- Shorter [strings] are better than longer ones.
> - ergonomics -- Human users (especially non-technical ones) should find the 
>     [strings] as easy and pleasant as possible.  The uglier the [strings] looks, the worse.

Comment: Cheers, I don t mind it is base 64 I think, It is a code that ppl can share(99% will be copy & paste) then import in the app, and they ll be able to see what items they have(true) or don t have(false).

Edit: I don t want to store it in a BitArray since it can grow(the list) so the size might increase, So it is easier to use a List<Boolean>. Right :p?

Comment: Just in case: [Base32Encoding Implementation For .NET](http://hemant-jangid.blogspot.com/2009/06/base32encoding-implementation-for-net.html)

Comment: I use a boolean list so the first part doesn t work, however the rest does, but I still need to find a way to get my  tmpboollist to Byte[].

Answer (score 3):

To start with, it's a bad idea to concatenate strings in a loop like that - at least use `StringBuilder`, or use something like this with LINQ:

```
string text = new string(tmpboolist.Select(x => x ? '1' : '0').ToArray());
```

But converting your string to a `List<bool>` is easy with LINQ, using the fact that `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`:

```
List<bool> values = text.Select(c => c == '1').ToList();
```

It's not clear where the byte array comes in... but you [should *not* try to represent arbitrary binary data in a string just using `Encoding.GetString`](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx). That's not what it's for.

If you don't care what format your string uses, then using Base64 will work well - but be aware that if you're grouping your Boolean values into bytes, you'll need extra information if you need to distinguish between "7 values" and "8 values, the first of which is False" for example.

Comment: Thank you for the nice help, Now I don t need to for loop anymore ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since I am infering from your code you want a string with n digits of either 1 or 0 depending onthe internal lists bool value then how about...

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(91);
    foreach(bool item in this.tempboolist)
    {
        output.Append(item ? "1" : "0");
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

Warning this was off the cuff typing, I have not validated this with a compiler yet!

Answer (score 0):

This function does what you want:

```
    public String convertBArrayToStr(bool[] input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            return "";
        int length = input.Count();
        int byteArrayCount = (input.Count() - 1) / 8 + 1;
        var bytes = new char[byteArrayCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
        {
            var mappedIndex = (i - 1) / 8;
            bytes[mappedIndex] = (char)(2 * bytes[mappedIndex] +(input[i] == true ? 1 : 0));
        }
        return new string(bytes);
    }
```