# Generate the shortest alphanumeric save code

Tags: c#, powerset

For the purpose of a game, I need to generate a save code that the user can note somewhere and use to reload his game state later (no persistent data possible).
The save code needs to be short like `6DZF1D3`, (a base 36 or base 62 string).

Scores of game levels can be simplified as a `string` like 1232312321321321321, a sequence where each char is a level score in "stars" (1, 2 or 3 stars). 
There will be around 30 game levels.

I would like to generate the shortest code possible for the user, so my first idea was to generate all possibilities inside an Array. Then generate the base 62 code of the key where the user is. But with 3^30 possibilities, this is generating an array with 2e+14 key/values, which is not good for memory and CPU.

Second thought, was to use a base 4 to 62 converter, but most of codes I found are using `int` or `long` which are limited in size and lower than 30 chars.

Do you have any idea of how to generate the shortest save code composed of alphanumeric chars ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user should be able to write it down i would prefer a Base58 encoding. So, for 1-3 possible stars per level we need 2 bits to encode each level.

```
00 => 0 star (would mean last unplayed level reached)
01 => 1 star
10 => 2 stars
11 => 3 stars
```

We need 60 bits for 30 levels, all levels with 3 stars would be decimal 1152921504606846975. This, base58 encoded, would be **3gDmDv6tjHG**, not too long, is it?!

**Update:**

@DrNootNoot I'm glad you found a way to solve your problem! But I had fun to hack a small piece of code for my mentioned base58 version. I adapted the two functions by Pavel Vladov you used.

Maybe someday someone else has a similar issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] scoreArray = new string[30] { "1", "2", "3", "3", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2","3" };

            ulong numScore = ScoreToDecimal(scoreArray);

            string saveScore = UDecimalToBase58String(numScore);

            Console.WriteLine("Score array: " + String.Join("-",scoreArray));
            Console.WriteLine("Numeric score: " + Convert.ToString(numScore));
            Console.WriteLine("Base58 score: " + saveScore);

            ulong numScoreRestored = Base58StringToUDecimal(saveScore);
            string[] scoreArrayRestored = DecimalToScore(numScoreRestored);

            Console.WriteLine("From Base58 converted numeric score: " + Convert.ToString(numScoreRestored));
            Console.WriteLine("From Base58 converted score array: " + String.Join("-", scoreArray));
            Console.Read();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the stars-per-level array to a decimal value for the saved game.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="score">score array to convert. Max. 32 entries/levels.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static ulong ScoreToDecimal(string[] score)
        {
            int arrLength = score.Length;

            if (arrLength > 32)
                throw new ArgumentException("The score array must not be larger than 32 entries");

            ulong result = 0;

            for (int i = arrLength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ulong singleScore = Convert.ToUInt64(score[i]);

                if (singleScore > 3)
                    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Invalid score value. Max. allowed value is 3, but {0} was given at index {1}", singleScore, i), "score");

                result += (singleScore << ((arrLength - 1 - i) * 2));
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the decimal value of the saved game back to a stars-per-level array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="decimalScore">Maximal 64-bit unsigned saved game number to convert.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string[] DecimalToScore(ulong decimalScore)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            while(decimalScore > 0)
            {
                result.Add(Convert.ToString(decimalScore % 4));
                decimalScore /= 4;
            }

            result.Reverse();
            return result.ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adapted Unsigned-Base58-Version of Pavel Vladovs DecimalToArbitrarySystem function.
        /// See: https://www.pvladov.com/2012/05/decimal-to-arbitrary-numeral-system.html
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="decimalNumber"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string UDecimalToBase58String(ulong decimalNumber)
        {
            const int BitsInLong = 64;
            const int FixedRadix = 58;
            const string Digits = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";

            if (decimalNumber == 0)
                return "0";

            int index = BitsInLong - 1;
            ulong currentNumber = decimalNumber;
            char[] charArray = new char[BitsInLong];

            while (currentNumber != 0)
            {
                int remainder = (int)(currentNumber % FixedRadix);
                charArray[index--] = Digits[remainder];
                currentNumber = currentNumber / FixedRadix;
            }

            string result = new String(charArray, index + 1, BitsInLong - index - 1);

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adapted Unsigned-Base58-Version of Pavel Vladovs ArbitraryToDecimalSystem function.
        /// See: https://www.pvladov.com/2012/07/arbitrary-to-decimal-numeral-system.html
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="base58String"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static ulong Base58StringToUDecimal(string base58String)
        {
            const int FixedRadix = 58;
            const string Digits = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(base58String))
                return 0;

            ulong result = 0;
            ulong multiplier = 1;
            for (int i = base58String.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                char c = base58String[i];
                int digit = Digits.IndexOf(c);
                if (digit == -1)
                    throw new ArgumentException(
                        "Invalid character in the arbitrary numeral system number",
                        "number");

                result += (uint)digit * multiplier;
                multiplier *= FixedRadix;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to reproduce this on my side !

Comment: I'm not sure how to play with bytes through, I guess I should not just convert 3e+30 to binary but rather use binary operations ?

Comment: base 36 is giving me only 1 more char so I think I will stick with it : 8RC4KBDVSS1R

Comment: 60 bits is too much. You only need 1.5 bits per level, because 0 stars is not an explicit option. Same as that in decimal we do not note the number 42 as 0000042, but just 42.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos I'm aware that the 0 isn't explicitly needed, but how would you endcode 1/2 bit?

Comment: @Yosh You are right. You'll need 2 bit, otherwise you cannot note down the least amount of stars in the last played level.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I think I'm gonna use your version as it's much more cleaner than mine, but gonna use base36 instead as having both upper and lower chars will end up making typo mistakes by the user. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to get binary data into a textual representation is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Each character represents 6 bits of information. You have just under 48 bits of information, which nicely gets you to 8 Base64 digits.

So the strategy would be:
     1. Convert your base 3 (star)array to base 2 using [this algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/10321).
     2. Convert the bits to a byte array [using Convert.ToByte();](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989766/598599)
     3. Use [Convert.ToBase64String()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.7.2) to create a Base64 string.

**Edit:** I realise you want to have it in a Base36, [there are some code examples that can do it.](https://www.stum.de/2008/10/20/base36-encoderdecoder-in-c/) This code needs a string as input, but converts it to a `char[]`, so you can just provide the ByteArray instead.

**Edit2:**
The proof is in the eating, just created a back and forth converter for any base up to base36 (but can be extended). For your stars, you only have to provide a string with the star values as numbers (1 to 3).

```
    private static string ConvertToOtherBase(string toConvert, int fromBase, int toBase)
    {
        const string characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        long value = 0;
        string result = "";

        foreach (char digit in toConvert.ToCharArray())
            value = (value * fromBase) + characters.IndexOf(digit);

        while (value > 0)
        {
            result = characters[(int)(value % toBase)] + result;
            value /= toBase;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

You can call it like this (back and forth):

```
        var stars = "112131121311213112131121311213";

        string base36Result = ConvertToOtherBase(stars, 4, 36);
        // 32NSB7MBR9T3

        string base4Result = ConvertToOtherBase(base36Result, 36, 4);
        // 112131121311213112131121311213
```

Comment: That `fromDigits` function is supposed to generate a `int` or `long`which is not big enough in my case ?

Comment: Same thing for the Base36.Encode(), it's taking a `long` input, not a `string`, so I'm limited to 22 chars, so but It can work if I'm generating the 2e+14 keys before, instead of passing my score string.. I

Comment: @DrNootNoot Of course the provided links are for inspiration and will not give you a direct solution. But because I really liked the mental challenge to do this in a clean way, I  just provided my own version that can be found in the second edit.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this question is opinion based but here is one simple way to save

Create object

```
public class Memento
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public int Level {get; set;}
     public int Score {get; set;}
}
```

then just use `Newtonsoft.Json` library to serialize it. On top of it, you can encrypt serialized JSON so user can't see insides of saved data, and write it to disk. But of course, there are many ways of persisting the score. By the way, name of my class should point you to a programming pattern that specifically solves this issue

**Update**

Reading your comment - is this what you looking for?

```
    int x = 5, y = 10;
    byte[]xb  = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
    var enumer  = xb.Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(y));
    string outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(enumer.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine(outStr);
    // your code: BQAAAAoAAAA=
```

And BTW, if you use int16, your code will be even shorter: `BQAKAA==`

```
    byte[] back = Convert.FromBase64String(outStr);
    short a = BitConverter.ToInt16(back, 0);
    short b = BitConverter.ToInt16(back, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(a + "_" + b);
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I'm looking to generate a short base 36 code that the user can write on a paper, and use it the next time (no persistent data possible)

Comment: @DrNootNoot You mean, a string like this `7G6`? you mean, you want to generate user code, which user will use later, manually?

Comment: Yeah that's it, I will edit my post as you explained it better ;)

Comment: Based on your update I did this function, but my 27 score string was converted to a 144 chars length base64 string :
 public static string Test(string s)
 {
  var lst = new List<byte>();
  foreach (char c in s)
  {
   lst.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)Char.GetNumericValue(c)));
  }
  string outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(lst.ToArray());
  return outStr;
 }

Comment: @DrNootNoot I just shortened it a bit

Comment: @DrNootNoot I thought, we're dealing with 2 integers, which together get you 8bytes. My code concatenates these bytes and creates base64 "code". to go back, you just do "fromBase64"- grab first 4 bytes and do `BitConverter.ToInt32` and then second set of 4 bytes. Then just convert it to stars and levels

Comment: Thank you for the serialization example, but yeah as you pointed, I dont need to store the level number, just a sequence of scores, like 321321321321332132132132133213213213213. to something like G6d3Z1m.

Comment: @DrNootNoot Bottom line, by looking at all the things here you can encode they way you want. Replace base64 with base36 function. No problem. But bytes operations will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

So this is the code I wrote with the idea of @Yosh and that functions : https://www.pvladov.com/2012/07/arbitrary-to-decimal-numeral-system.html

```
string code = "";
string[] scoreArray = new string[100];
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, LevelScore> l in scores)
{
    scoreArray[l.Value.levelNum - 1] = Convert.ToString(l.Value.stars, 2).PadLeft(2, '0');
}
for (int s = 0; s < scoreArray.Length; s++)
{
    code = scoreArray[s] + code;
}
string b2 = code ;// like "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
print("b2 " + b2);

long b10 = ScoreUtils.ArbitraryToDecimalSystem(b2, 2);
print("b10 " + b10);

string b36 = ScoreUtils.DecimalToArbitrarySystem(b10, 36);
print("b36 " + b36);
```