# How do I Convert Bits to Bytes?

Tags: byte, bit

If I have a x-bit value represented as 1s and 0s representing true and false respectively. How would I convert these to 8-bit bytes? I don't want to know how to convert the number of bits to the number of bytes(x/8). I want to know how to convert something like this:

10000010 to a byte

or

100000101000001 to a float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is moot (without more information).  Bits may be represented in multiple orders (endians), with the low order bit coming first or last.  You need to have a defined endian order.  Once you move from single bytes to words, the endian question becomes even more challenging since the order of bits may be different from the order of the bytes.

Moving from integers to floating point numbers is yet another level of complexity.  Floating point numbers have different representations which are entirely different from the order of bits.

Portable code will use defined representations (network order, printf, etc) and stay far away from trying to hand-pack bits.

Comment: The thought that whether it was big-endian or little-endian only effected the byte ordering.

Answer (score 1):

```
bytes[byteIndex] |= (byte)(1 << (7-bitIndex));
```

refer to:

[How can I convert bits to bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/719502/735864)

Comment: I was referring to a mathematical method, not one that is programmatic. And if you do provide a programmatic solution, please give some explanation

Answer (score 0):

So I am guessing that you want
1 converted to 1,
10 converted to 2,
11 converted to 3,
etc.,
1001011 is converted to 1*2^0 + 1*2^1 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^3 + 0*2^4+ 0*2^5 + 1*2^6 = 75

EDIT: For example with JavaScript:

```
function binarytodecimal(input,l)
                    {
                    var i=0;
                    var dec=0;
                    while (i<l)
                        {
                            var temp1 = parseInt(input.charAt(l-1-i));
                            dec = dec + temp1*Math.pow(2,i);
                            i++;
                        }
                    dec = dec+'';
                    return dec;
                    }
```