# Encode bool array as ushort

Tags: c#, arrays, encoding, bit

Let's assume we have an array of Boolean values, some are true some are false.
I like to generate a `ushort` and set the bits according to the array.

A `ushort` consists of 2 bytes, - that makes up 16 bits.

So the first bool in the array need to set the first bit of the `ushort` if it's true, otherwise the bit would be 0.
This needs to be repeated for each bit in the `ushort`.

How would I setup a method stub which takes an array of bools as input and returns the encoded ushort? (C#)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the BitConverter class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx) in order to convert from bytes to an int, and binary operations (like in this StackOverflow question: [How can I convert bits to bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719502/how-can-i-convert-bits-to-bytes)) to convert from bits to bytes

For Example:

```
//Bools to Bytes...
bool[] bools = ...
BitArray a = new BitArray(bools);
byte[] bytes = new byte[a.Length / 8];
a.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
//Bytes to ints
int newInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes); //Change the "32" to however many bits are in your number, like 16 for a short
```

This will only work for one int, so if you have multiple int's  in a single bit array, you'll need to split up the array for this approach to work.

Answer (score 1):

A BitArray might be more suitable for your use case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx

```
bool[] myBools = new bool[5] { true, false, true, true, false };
BitArray myBA = new BitArray(myBools);

foreach (var value in myBA)
{
    if((bool)value == true)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, please, _please_ don't use `booleanValue == true`.  It's not as readable, and for performance junkies, it performs unnecessary operations that consume (albeit small amounts of) processor time.  Instead, please just put `booleanValue` directly into the  `if` statements, or wherever the boolean is being used.